# Tableview section By Date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How to group data in  the tableview by date in Xcode?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [DateSectionTitles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html) sample app. It demonstrates a tableview with date cells grouped by the month. It is based on CoreData.

[image: Screenshot of DateSectionTitles]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to find reasonable date groups: month, week, year-month combination etc. After that you'll have to find a method which can determine which of your cell has to go to which group/section, described as an NSIndexPath. numberOfSections as well as numberOfRowsInSection has to reflect your grouping idea. With the UITableViewDataSource protocol you can provide the names for your sections with titleForHeaderInSection:.