# tableView section based on string

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm looking for something like this
[Tableview section By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289813/tableview-section-by-date)

instead of a date, I have a NSMutableArray that contains information like...

14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16... etc (all in string)

I would like to section them based on those strings (which are days of the month).
no need to rearrange.

Comment: Is it an array of dictionaries or just strings?

Comment: just strings. no need to rearrange if they're messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst I am not sure if this is exactly what you want, let's assume that your array is name `numbers`.

```
NSCountedSet * numberSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:numbers];
NSArray * sortedSections = [[[numberSet allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)] retain];
```

Now,

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [sortedSections count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableVIew numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [numberSet countForObject:[sortedSections objectAtIndex:section]];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [..]

    cell.textLabel.text = [sortedSections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    return cell;
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return sortedSections;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [sortedSections objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: works like a charm but the app crashed when i performed insertion/deletion. any idea why?

Comment: How are you performing an insertion or deletion?